# Top & Left vs margin-top & margin-left

Tags: html, css, layout

What is the difference between using top and left properties and top and left margins?

I know top and left are usually used in position:absolute situation but I'm still wondering if there is any major difference.

ex:

```
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:5px;
```

-vs-

```
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:5px;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, the main difference is that absolutely positioned elements are pulled out of the content flow.

But also with relatively positioned elements, the surrounding content may become obfuscated.

Margins on the other hand are added to the element's size while the surrounding content flows accordingly.

See [this sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/qbryN/) with some differences.

Surely there are situations where both deliver the same results, but under normal conditions, these two aproaches aren't simply exchangeable nor comparable.

Answer (score 5):

Margin describes the space between your box and adjacent boxes. Boxes that are positioned relatively (i.e. that are part of the normal flow) will keep the sufficient space between them that each one's "margin" requirements are met (called "margin collapsing").

`top` and `left` on the other hand are *positional* attributes that specify *where* your box is located; for absolutely positioned boxes the values are taken relative to the nearest containing box which is itself absolutely positioned. The top/left/bottom/right attributes specify the location of the respective edge of your box including its margin.

In short, the two are entirely different concepts. For normally flowed boxes you should use `margin` to control the spacing between neighbouring boxes.

Comment: `only for boxes that are positioned relatively... Margin values are ignored on absolutely positioned boxes` Not true. Margin works for all position types.

Comment: @Jeff: What do you mean by "works"? What is the effect of a margin on an absolutely positioned box? *Edit:* Oh, yes, you are right of course, the margin is _included_ in the absolute positioning. Thanks! I will update the post.

Answer (score 5):

**A** There's a *semantic* difference. Box offsets like `top` specify how far a box's margin edge (dotted edges in the image below) is offset from a reference edge (For absolutely positioned elements, that's the top edge of the box's containing block). Margin properties like `margin-top` specify the width of the margin area of a box (The distance `TM` between the dotted edge and and solid edge in the image below).

[image: Box model]

**B** `top` and `left` apply only to positioned elements (elements with `position` set to anything other than `static`) while `margin-top` and `margin-left` apply to all elements except elements with table display types other than table-caption, table and inline-table.