# css "left" not working

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have 2 divs, parent and child, I want that child left side (left border) will in center of parent.

Why this code not working? that is `left: 50%` for child, is not working.

```
<div id="outher">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#outher {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 1000px;
   background-color: #ccc;
}

#inner {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #090;
   left: 50%;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/vrse2/5/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to set `position` to `absolute` or `relative`:

```
#inner {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #090;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

CSS `left` only works with positioned elements.

[Quoted from W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/left)

```
Values  <length> | <percentage> | auto | inherit
Initial value   auto
Applies to  positioned elements
Inherited   No
```

Try

```
#inner {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #090;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
}
```

---

**Good read**

1. [**MDN : CSS Reference -left (Best IMHO)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/left)
2. [W3C : CSS/Properties/left](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/left)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `position: absolute;` to your CSS. `left` is used for absolute positioning.

In your case:

```
#inner {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #090;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
margin-left: 50%;
```

Or:

```
position:relative;
left:50%;
```

Comment: `margin-left` is something totally different. For more info on this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419411/top-left-vs-margin-top-margin-left.

Answer (score 2):

***Try With the following :***

**HTML Part :**

```
<div id="outher">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Part :**

```
#outher {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#inner {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #090;
    left: 50%;  
    margin:0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.