# how to set an element at fixed relative position in html rendering.?

Tags: html, css

I have some elements on the html page.

All elements do not start vertically with same relative pixel(say all start from vertically centre line of the window..).

how do i set all these element start vertically with the same relative pixel??

i am trying with 'left' css property. but it doesn't work.

```
left: 50%!important;
```

In short with this http://jsfiddle.net/EPREq/ i want both the 'Koka' word should start from the same vertical line. Please don't use HTML table to do this. Using table in my page will have many problems.

Comment: Can you post your code? It would make helping you easier.

Comment: It isn't totally clear what it is you're asking at this point.  Take a couple of minutes to put together an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which demonstrates what you're describing and I'm sure someone will be able to help!

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EPREq/ and please go through the edit

Comment: updated : http://jsfiddle.net/EPREq/1/

Comment: `left` requires you to set a `position` property...It won't do anything on it's own. `position:absolute; top:0; left:0`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171855/css-left-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me :

http://jsfiddle.net/EPREq/6/

```
<div>
    <span class="a" > Hi </span>
    <span class="b">Koka</span> 
 </div>

<div>
    <span class= "a"> Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii </span>
    <span class= "b">Koka</span> 
 </div>


.a {
   width : 300px; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.b {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
margin-left:50% !important;
```