# JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, console.log

This is a really annoying error and there seems to be various questions about this console error. It doesn't give me a whole lot to work with in the console using chrome.

```
 /**
     * Dropdown menu positioning
     */
    loc.dropMenuPositioning = function (){
        var dropMenu = $('.js-dropdown-item-wrap');
        var mainNavigationOffset = $('.js-nav-container > ul').offset();
        var mainNavigationPosition = mainNavigationOffset.left;
        dropMenu.css({'left' : mainNavigationPosition - 60});
    };
```

Sorry, i don't have much more to go with on this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `$nothing.offset()` is `null` which would throw an error when trying to access a property of it. Perhaps the issue is that the `$('.js-nav-container > ul')` isn't finding anything.

Comment: Tip: try using the Chrome debugger and setting a breakpoint on the first line of your function. Then inspect the value of each variable.

Comment: What is the value of mainNavigationOffset after you initialize it?

Comment: @sdgluck, not sure how to set a breaking point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading the property *left* from an object returned in the previous row. The line that fails is:

```
var mainNavigationPosition = mainNavigationOffset.left;
```

The error means that mainNavigationOffset is undefined.

Because mainNavigationOffset is set as:

```
var mainNavigationOffset = $('.js-nav-container > ul').offset();
```

it is possible that jquery was not able to get the offset of the element  $('.js-nav-container > ul').

As stated by the jquery documentation:

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the
>   body element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with
>   visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering
>   tree and thus has a position that is undefined.

**Check that the element is actually visible.**

**Another option (that seems what really happened) is that the jquery expression:**

```
$('.js-nav-container > ul')
```

**is not returning any element.**

To see if the element is visible, you can use the chrome dev tool:

*display* must not be equals to none
[image: display should not be equals to none]

visibility must be equals to visible
[image: visibility should be equals to visible]

Or you can simply execute in the console:

```
$('.js-nav-container > ul').css("display");
$('.js-nav-container > ul').css("visibility");
```

Comment: How do i check that the element is actually visible? How should i move forward?

Comment: It looks like you may be right, when i evaluate the function i get this...  Uncaught ReferenceError: mainNavigationOffset is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM95:1

Comment: I added a couple of screenshots to show how to check the visibility in chrome dev tools.

Comment: That view should be opened for the element that you want to check.

Comment: display equals block and I don't see visibility at all. I'm attaching a screen shot.

Comment: I added a couple of commands that will be easier to use to read the value of display and visibility with jquery

Comment: Your screenshot is showing the properties for "body" and not for the element in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103026/discussion-between-supple-and-marco-altieri).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset-coordinates)

```
dropMenu.offset({ left: mainNavigationPosition - 60 });
```

Otherwise, you might need to set the position to absolute or relative:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171855/css-left-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your jQuery version is up to 1.2, the .offset() method may not work in older versions.

[jQuery 1.2 change log](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.2/)