# keycodes not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

> this does not move the box when pressing the right and left arrow.
>   please post in the comments if you can help.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", testkey , false );
var el = document.getElementById("player");
//changes the x position by a value
function changex(num) {
    el.style.left = ((num + el.style.left) + "px");
}
//changes the y position by a value
function changey(num2) {
    el.style.top = ((num2 + el.style.top) + "px");
}
//sets x and y position of box
function setpos(x, y) {
    el.style.left = (x + "px");
    el.style.top = (y + "px");
}
//this returns the key that is pressed
function testkey(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "37") {
        //left key
        changex(-10);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == "39") {
        //right key
        changex(10);
    }
}
setpos(0,0);
```

Comment: Why are you comparing e.keyCode to a string with type coersion??? Just put `e.keyCode === 37`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues:

### First

You are adding numeric values to strings, which results in concatination. For example:
`((num + el.style.left) + "px")` is equivalent to `10 + 0px + px`, which results in a string like `100pxpx`. This is not a valid CSS value.

I suggest using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert existing style values from strings to numbers:
    `el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) + num + "px";`

For further reference, see [Get a number for a style value WITHOUT the “px;” suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690463/get-a-number-for-a-style-value-without-the-px-suffix).

### Second

You'll need to [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) the element before you can use `left`,`right`,`top`, or `bottom` CSS definitions. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) notes that `left` (for example) only applies to "positioned elements".

Below, I've used `position:absolute`, but any valid position value will work.

For further reference, see [css “left” not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171855/css-left-not-working).

### Working Example

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", testkey, false);
var el = document.getElementById("player");

function changex(num) {
  el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) + num + "px";
}

function changey(num) {
  el.style.top = parseInt(el.style.top) + num + "px";
}

function setpos(x, y) {
  el.style.left = (x + "px");
  el.style.top = (y + "px");
}

function testkey(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: changex(-10); break;
    case 38: changey(-10); break;
    case 39: changex(10); break;
    case 40: changey(10); break;
    default:
  }

}

setpos(0, 0);
```

```css
#player {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for figuring out this problem I was having I voted your answer up to give you some reputation

Answer (score 0):

in your `changex()` and `changey()` functions, you're trying to do calculations between a number and a string.  `num` comes in as a number but `el.style.left` is the string '0px'.  put `parseInt()` around `el.style.left` like this and it works:

```
el.style.left = ((num + parseInt(el.style.left)) + "px");
```

Also make sure your `player` element has `position:absolute` applied via CSS.