# Difference between margin-left and left when the position set absolute

Tags: css, position, absolute

`1.position:absolute;left:200px;`

`2.position:absolute；margin-left:200px;`

Is there any differences about the above style?

Comment: Do you mean differences in appearance or differences in what's actually happening?

Comment: Duplicate, find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419411/top-left-vs-margin-top-margin-left

Comment: I don't see any difference in appearance.Is there any difference in mechanism?

Comment: If you look at the duplicate answer that @kenttam gave, it indicates that whether there are visible differences will depend upon the scenario.

Comment: If you take a look this example: http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/qbryN/, there is a difference in appearance depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a subtle difference.

Consider the following example:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="ex1">Ex 1</div>
    <div class="ex2">Ex 2</div>
    <div class="ex3">Ex 3</div>
</div>

body {
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
    margin: 0 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
.ex1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: beige;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.ex2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: beige;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.ex3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; /* so you can see what is happening */
    left: 0px;
    background-color: beige;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

And see the results at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/WQA6B/

In Example 1 (`.ex1`), the margin is 50px from the left edge of the parent container (`.wrap`).

In Example 2 (`.ex2`) the element is 50px from the left edge of the view port.

To get `.ex2` to behave similarly to `.ex1`, you would need to set `position: relative`
to `.wrap` so both div's are positioned with respect to the same context.

There is yet another factor.  In Example 1, I did not specify any offsets, so the element remains in the position if would have been if you had used `position: static`, which is why the margin is computed with respect to the left edge of the wrapper.

If I had set `left: 0` (see Example 3) you would have gotten a result similar to Example 2.

Answer (score 3):

Even though they can do similar things, they are completely different.

**Margin** is part of the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), which also includes `padding` and `border`. Box model styles change the size of the object itself.

For instance, if you have an image with the below style:

```
.my_box {
  display:block;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

The elements with the `my_box` class would get 10 pixels margin added on the left side of the box.

**Top, left, etc**

These are `positions`, which instead of adding to the size of the elements box model, literally [tell the elements where to be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```
.my_box {
  display:block;
  left:10px;
}
```

The above style would tell that element to be 10 pixels from the left of its container (if `position:relative`, or the page (if `position:absolute`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is difference.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xk8Lz/

Attention to `10px padding` in "parent" elements to absolute positioned element. Paddings and borders will affect margin in absolute positioned Div.

Left will count from beginning of "parent" element.

Code:

```
<div class="left">
    left parent
    <div class="abs">Left</div>    
</div>

<div class="marginLeft">
    margin left parent
    <div class="abs">Margin-Left</div>    
</div>
```

Css:

```
div, span {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
.left, .marginLeft {
    background: #aaf;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.marginLeft {
}
.abs {
    background: #faa;
    position: absolute;
        top: 0;
}
.left .abs {
    left: 100px;
}
.marginLeft .abs {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```