# Can't get margin-bottom to work on search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The only margin attribute that works is margin-left on my search box. When I try to add margin-bottom, the search box does not move. I then tried changing the display to "block" but then the search box goes all the way to the left of my screen, and stays stuck.

Is there anyway to free up margin so that I can move my search box in 360 degree points around the screen?

Here is the code that gets stuck on margin-left:

```
<input class="search" type="text" name="q" id="q" size="40" maxlength="50" style=  "display:block; position:relative;margin-left:-15%";>
```

here is a fiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/4d4c2zdn/1/

Comment: If you're doing inline-styles, `style=  "display:block"; "position:relative";"margin-left:-15%";` is invalid. It should be: `style="display:block; position:relative; margin-left: -15%;"`

Comment: I fixed it, but the margin-bottom is still not working.

Comment: The search box just gets stuck, I can't move it.

Comment: margin-bottom is working,but give 3000px ,u will see scroll bar is appear as it move from bottom to 3000px position...

Comment: Better to create a fiddle or a snippet on this one

Comment: Ok, I created a fiddle to show what I am talking about.

Comment: try using margin only like margin:top-bottom left-right(eg 30px 30px) and so on

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that your margin-left is given a negative value? The margin-bottom is only going to push down things below it in the layout. Are you trying to move the search box up?

When relatively positioning an element with `position:relative;` you can use basic positioning like `left:15%;` or `right: -15%;` as well. This should free up your margin.

[I made a pen to better explain the situation.](http://codepen.io/simgooder/pen/meVByM)

Comment: Yeah I am aware about the negative value. I am trying to push the search box down, but it does not work with margin-bottom. I tampered with it some more, and margin-top, and margin-left are the only ones that work. Margin-bottom and Margin-right do not work. Paradoxically 'left', 'right', 'top', and 'bottom' DO work, as long as I don't put margin in there. Any idea why this is?

Comment: This provides a good explanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419411/top-left-vs-margin-top-margin-left